# Magento set html data in layout xml

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, template

I have a payment method block. I saw that I can add custom HTML after the label in one page payment using the getMethodLabelAfterHtml method.

I want to be able to pass a HTML string to the setMethodLabelAfterHtml of my payment method.

```
<checkout_onepage_paymentmethod>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml">
        <block type="core/template" name="payment.method.cashondelivery">
            <action method="setMethodLabelAfterHtml">
                <block type="core/template" name="payment.method.cashondelivery.picto" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/payment/cashondelivery.phtml" />
            </action>
        </block>
    </block>
</checkout_onepage_paymentmethod>
```

I am unable to get the `toHTML` version of my template `cashondelivery.phtml` and pass it to the `setMethodLabelAfterHtml` action all only using the xml layout files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use helpers to get the value for a specific parameter:
Something like this:

```
<block type="core/template" name="payment.method.cashondelivery">
    <action method="setMethodLabelAfterHtml">
         <html helper="[helper_alias]/getCacheOnDeliveryHtml" />
    </action>
</block>
```

now you need to create a module with a helper and in that helper add this:

```
public function getCacheOnDeliveryHtml()
{
    $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')
           ->setTemplate('checkout/onepage/payment/cashondelivery.phtml');
    return $block->toHtml();
}
```